# How do I pipe a single number to get a list?

Tags: elixir

I have a single element/number that I am piping to `Enum.into([])` but Elixir throws `** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for 90`

```
90 |> Enum.into([])

v = 65
v |> Enum.into([]) Enumerable not implemented for 65
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `List.wrap/1` and not `|> Enum.into([])`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Enum.into/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#into/2) expects an Enumerable as the first argument, hence the error.

To pipe a Single Element into a list, use [List.wrap](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/List.html#wrap/1)

```
65 |> List.wrap
```

Answer (score -1):

```
iex(1)> n = [1]

[1]

iex(2)> Enum.into(n, [ ])  
[1]

iex(3)> n |> Enum.into([ ])  
[1]
```

Comment: You should add explanation.